# SQL - Filter using another table

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I have 2 tables:

```
  spec_tb

  j_id     param     relation_id     param_val
  1        role      1               Manager
  1        role      1               Owner
  1        role      1               Developer
  1        title     1               COO
  1        title     1               Marketing Head
  1        title     1               CEO
```

2nd table

```
user

user_id     role         title
1           Manager      xCOO
2           Owner        abcCEO
3           Developer    WWW
```

Using `spec_tb`, I need to match all `param_val` where `param = 'role'` with `role` column of `contact` table
and 
`param_val` where `param = 'title'` with `title` column of `contact` table

So, I need to take all the combination from spec_tb and filter in user as below:

```
select param_val from spec_tb where j_id = 1 and param = role;
select param_val from spec_tb where j_id = 1 and param = title;
```

- role = Manager and title = COO
- role = Manager and title = Marketing Head
- role = Manager and title = CEO
- role = Owner and title = COO
- role = Owner and title = Marketing Head
- role = Owner and title = CEO
- role = Developer and title = COO
- role = Developer and title = Marketing Head
- role = Developer and title = CEO

The query would be for all the above combinations:

```
select user_id from user where role = [ROLE] and title like '%' || [TITLE] || '%';
```

So, the query would be like:

```
select user_id from user where role = 'Manager' and title like '%' || 'COO
' || '%'
union
select user_id from user where role = 'Manager' and title like '%' || 'Marketing Head' || '%'
union
select user_id from user where role = 'Manager' and title like '%' || 'CEO
' || '%'
union
select user_id from user where role = 'Owner' and title like '%' || 'COO
' || '%'
union
select user_id from user where role = 'Owner' and title like '%' || 'Marketing Head' || '%'
union
select user_id from user where role = 'Owner' and title like '%' || 'CEO
' || '%'
union
select user_id from user where role = 'Developer' and title like '%' || 'COO
' || '%'
union
select user_id from user where role = 'Developer' and title like '%' || 'Marketing Head' || '%'
union
select user_id from user where role = 'Developer' and title like '%' || 'CEO
' || '%';
```

The results for the above example would be:

```
user_id
1
2
```

But I want to generate an optimized version of the query using spec_tb.

How to write SQL query to do so?

Comment: I am using ilike for case insensitive check.

Comment: Why are using '%' || [TITLE] || '%' instead of '%TITLE%'

Comment: I need to get this dynamically from spec_tb from the column - param_val

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: There is no error, I don't know how to join 2 tables in SQL to get the expected result.